# Неправильное отображение интерфейса и проблема с OpenGL

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, rdp, облако, yandex-cloud

1. Арендовал машину с vGPU в Яндекс.Облаке на Ubuntu 20.04.
2. Установил ubuntu-desktop, vncserver.
3. Подключился к удалённому рабочему столу.

Во всех туториалах открывается классическая Ubuntu с красивым рабочим столом и т.д.

У меня появляется следующее нечто:

[image: нечто]

Также, при запуске glxgears появляется ошибка:

[image: ошибка в glxgears]

Comment: А что говорит поддержка?

Comment: Ну и кстати, vncserver по умолчанию создает свои иксы, в которых аппаратное ускорение не работает

Comment: То есть, скорее всего, на машине, помимо того X-сервера, что был запущен вами, есть еще один, который запускает система. И вот в нем-то ускорение будет.

Comment: Выглядит как раз как классическая Ubuntu, только не знаю где там кому-то мог померещится красивый рабочий стол.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для полноценной работы vgpu в ЯО надо активировать лицензию от nvidia.
Вот [тут](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/compute/concepts/gpus#vgpu) описано:

```
Чтобы воспользоваться технологией vGPU, необходимы:

ВМ на платформе vgpu-standard-v1 с одним из образов:
    Ubuntu 18.04 lts vGPU;
    Windows Server 2019 Datacenter vGPU.
Лицензия для использования технологии NVIDIA® vGPU.
Сервер лицензий NVIDIA® vGPU Software License Server.
```